# TabHost - get selector to work for inner child of tab view?

Tags: android

I have a TabHost, and each of my tabs are individual views which look like:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView />
  <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

I can set a selector on the parent LinearLayout so that when the user touches the tab, its background changes, but the child ImageView (with the same selector pattern) does not get its state changed. Trying the following:

```
<item 
  android:state_focused="true" 
  android:state_pressed="true" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/plz_hilite_me" />
```

This works for the final focus state of the tab, both the parent LinearLayout and the child ImageView have the hilited backgrounds specified in the selector displayed. It's just the initial touch state which doesn't seem to get triggered for the inner child.

Hard to explain, hope that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

worked.

Comment: Great, was looking for this everywhere! Nice one :)